# Symfony app show .php extension in url and loop login page

Tags: php, apache, symfony, mod-rewrite

I have a website made with Symfony 2.8.22 running with Apache 2.4.18. I have `RewriteEngine` activated in the virtualhost to not show the .php extension in the url. However I have 2 problems. The first one is I do get the .php extension via url. The second problem is I have a loop in the login page; once I input the credentials it reloads the same login page again, and again. That happens in Chrome and Firefox, however in Microsoft Edge that loop wont happen, it just follow to the next page.

Why is that?

Where's my virtualhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ip.ip.ip.ip

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/website/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule (.*)\.php $1 [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/project>
        Options FollowSymlinks
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_website.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_website.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain why you are trying to forcably remove .php from the web address bar. If you follow the [Symfony Configuration guide](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) it will give you an .htaccess file that works and will not display .php extensions:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/web
    <Directory /var/www/project/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    # optionally disable the RewriteEngine for the asset directories
    # which will allow apache to simply reply with a 404 when files are
    # not found instead of passing the request into the full symfony stack
    <Directory /var/www/project/web/bundles>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```